# Pass c3js chart options to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, d3.js, c3.js

I have several different charts that I am rendering with c3js via ajax, and I currently have a lot of repeated ajax code that I would like to cut down on.

Each ajax call on success generates a c3js chart, but with different display types/options. Is there a way I can have a generic c3js generate and just pass in the options?

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {'chart': chart, 'start': start, 'end': end},
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function () {
        //code
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            //code                      
            c3.generate({
                bindto: '#chart-data',
                data: {
                    columns: data.active,
                    type: 'area',
                    groups: [data.groups]
                },
                axis: {
                    x: {
                        type: 'category',
                        categories: data.span
                    },
                    y: {
                        label: 'Label'
                    }
                 }
            });
        } else {
            //code
        }
    }
});
```

Repeated several times with various chart data types, groups, columns, axis, etc.

What I want:

```
var chart_options = {bindto: '#chart-data', data:{columns.data.active} //...
function generateChart(param1, param2, param3, chart_options) {
    //do some stuff
    //ajax call from above
    // ....
    // on success:
    // c3.generate(chart_options)
}
```

However when I do it this way, because the data.success is inside the function, and I am passing columns: data.active from outside the function, I receive javascript errors for data[i] column not defined.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var chart_options = {bindto: '#chart-data', {data: {type: "area"}} //...}
function generateChart(param1, param2, param3) {
  //do some stuff
  //ajax call from above
  // ....
  // on success:
  // chart_options.data.colums = data.active;
  // chart_options.data.groups = [data.groups];
  // same for axes…
  // c3.generate(chart_options)
}
```